# How to change permission targets in Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

Please do not write that I need to change the application manifest. Read this first.

I have an application that blocks incoming calls from numbers that are not in the user's phone book. To do this, I need several dangerous permissions, including: android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS, android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG. That's not all, but problems arise because of these.

The first time I clicked the Publish App button, the Play Console asked me for the purpose of those permissions. I chose that I need these permissions to block spam. It looks like there were some more suitable options that I needed to choose.

Google declined the update and asked me to select all applicable target options.
[image]
And here's my question: where to choose these goals? This window appeared only once, when it was first published. I didn't press any special buttons. I have already submitted the application for review three more times, but this window does not appear again. And the app is not published.
The documentation contains a description of these targets along with an indication of the permissions, but does not say how to change them.

I know it is possible to change the app's permissions in the manifest, but that doesn't work for me because then the app won't work.